# What is the difference between 暍 and 热?

Tags: meaning, usage, meaning-in-context, difference, characters

大家好

What is the difference between 暍 and 热 and when they are used ?

谢谢

Comment: look it up in a dictionary and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

字典显示的意思：
暍 yē
meaning：
(1) 中暑 [suffer heatstroke]
(2) 暑热;热 [heat]【hot】

暍有热的意思，但这是一个很不常用的字，而“热”是很常用的字。平时当温度比较高的时候，人们会说“天气很热”“我很热”等。

Comment: special note：`我很热` does not mean `i'm hot`, `我很热` means `it is melting hot now`. :)